# jquery - Change the position right of a div on document load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that I want to initially hide when the document is loaded, and animate it so that it will look like it is swiping in from outside.

My html is simple:

```
<div></div>
```

And the css:

```
div 
{
    position: absolute;
    right:-10000px;
}
```

The jquery is like:

```
$(".whyus").animate({
    right:"50px"
},5000);
```

The div is initially having `right:-10000px;` to get it completely out of the page. I want that if the page is loaded, the `div` will be animated in 5 seconds into the page with the right value of just `50px`. How can I get this to work?

Comment: use `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: imagine that page in a browser that renders that 10000px :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to give `right:-10000px;`. You can do by `right:-10vw;`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/5e93m91e/)

```js
$("div").animate({
  right: "50px"
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  right:-100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me!

Just changed the CSS to make things visible:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    right:-50px;
    //bit realistic height:100px;
    width:50px;
    border:1 px solid;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6ev5mhg/) for you

See if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I've made this [fiddle](http://codepen.io/rmfranciacastillo/pen/mevzQE) for you. Hope this helps.

Just needed to include

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.whyus').animate({right: "+=500px",}, 5000 );
});
```